# cross-server access to SQL Server FileTable share

Tags: sql-server, azure, filetable

Can you point me to any information about cross-server access to the SQL Server FileTable share?  We wanted to use this to manage variable-content for our Web Applications (which are running in a load-balanced configuration).  The share works great when local on the SQL Server VM, but when trying to connect to it from a Web Server VM it doesn’t work, no matter what domain account I’m running under (even a domain account with SQL Server SysAdmin).

Note that we have connectivity to SQL Server, just not the FileTable file share. That connectivity is across the private subnet.  Our private AD has DNS records only for the private network of the machines within the our private domain.

When running a command prompt on the VM hosting SQL Server and using a domain account that does NOT have any database permissions, we get the expected result (`access denied`) when trying to access the FileTable share: `<image>`

When running a command prompt on the VM hosting SQL Server and using a domain account that DOES HAVE database permissions, we also get the expected result (`access`) when trying to access the FileTable share: `<image>`

When running a command prompt on one of the Web Server VMs and using a domain account that DOES HAVE database permissions, we get an UNEXPECTED result (`device is not ready`) when trying to access the FileTable share: `<image>`

From the web server we can connect to the default share on any of the disks attached to the SQL Server VM: `<image>`

I’ve searched extensively and looked at many articles which describe setup and using SQL Server FileTables.  None of these articles describe the problem I’m seeing.

Left to my own devices, my next step would be to configure `FileTable`s in a non-Azure environment to see if results are similar.  But that’s a lot of work that I don’t have time to do.  As a work-around, I might use SSIS to mirror the SQL Server FileTable share across another share on the SQL Server VM so that the applications running on the Web servers can get access to the FileTable share indirectly.

Do you have any idea what it is that I might not be thinking of?  How can we connect to the SQL Server FileTable share from another machine?  Can you point me to any resource that might be able to help resolve this issue?